# How to exclude/ignore directories using command prompt when printing recursive list with FOR /R

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, directory

I want to ignore two directories, folders named "~downloads" and "~unsorted". This is the command I have so far which lists the path to every mp4 file:

```
for /r %i in (*.mp4) do @echo %~pnxi >> list.txt
```

Now I just need it to ignore directories "~downloads" and "~unsorted". How can that be done?

Comment: `dir /S /A-D /B *.mp4 |findstr /i /v "~downloads ~unsorted" >>list.txt`

Comment: @Squashman Works! Thank you!